# In docker-compose, how do I connect an app in one container to a postgres db in another container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm a beginner at docker and new to docker-compose. I am trying to get a project running with docker compose. When My backend app tries to connect to the db, I get this error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

Can you see anything wrong with my compose file that could cause it to not connect?

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/var/lib/db
    ports:
     - "5432"
  backup:
    image: ubuntu
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/var/lib/backup/data
  backend:
    image: java
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/var/lib/backup/data
      - ~/code/myCode:/usr/src/app/
    command: sh /usr/src/app/Docker/docker-setup.sh
    expose:
      - "8000"


volumes:
  data-volume:
```

Comment: Shouldn't you map the container port to the host port like this `- "5432:5432"`?

Answer (score 3):

Your db is not in the `localhost` of your Java container. You can point in your Java configuration to Postgres as this: `db:5432`
Also you can a link from your Java container to db to start in order:

```
backend:
    image: java
    links:
    - db
    (...the rest...)
```

Maybe you will need to wait that Postgres open its port 5432 **before** Java starts (I don't know if it is mandatory). If you need that, the common way is to add a wait-for-it.sh script (available on GitHub), modifying the command:

`command: /wait-for-it.sh db:5432 -- sh /usr/src/app/Docker/docker........`

Comment: You can also use `depends_on` to require that db has started before backend starts. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#dependson

Comment: I thought that in `docker-compose.yml` files above version 2 the services are in the same network so they should not be explicitly linked.

Comment: Filtfilt, you're right. But expressing links give some startup order. *Links also express dependency between services in the same way as depends_on, so they determine the order of service startup.*